# Redirecting to an ErrorPage via IRequestCycleListener Wicket

Tags: wicket, custom-error-pages

In the project I use Wicket 9.12.0.
If I use a ErrorPage without parameters:

`"getApplicationSettings().setInternalErrorPage(ErrorPage.class);"`

Then with the exception everything works fine.

If I use the ErrorPage with parameters via IRequestCycleListener:

`"getRequestCycleListeners().add(new IRequestCycleListener() { @Override public IRequestHandler onException(RequestCycle cycle, Exception ex) { if(ex instanceof RuntimeException){ PageParameters pageParameters=new PageParameters(); pageParameters.add("errorCode",500); cycle.setResponsePage(ErrorPage.class,pageParameters); } return null; } });"`

When excluded:

1. IRequestCycleListener works out (called:
   `cycle.setResponsePage(ErrorPage.class,pageParameters);
2. the page is being created (called:
    `public ErrorPage(PageParameters pageParameters){ int errorCode=pageParameters.get("errorCode").toInt(); add(new Label("error",getMessage(errorCode))); }`

But it is not the ErrorPage that is output, but the stack of exceptions.

Why is it not happening redirect to ErrorPage?
Сould an unhandled RuntimeException be the cause?

I want to create one page for all exceptions.
And only transmit the reason in the parameters.

Comment: What do you mean with ` but the stack of exceptions` ? Is this the Tomcat's error page ? If this is the case then I guess a new exception is being thrown while constructing the ErrorPage instance.

Comment: Do you have any error mappings (`<error-page``) in your web.xml ?

Comment: Yes, this is the ToIs this the Tomcat's error pagemcat's error page.

Comment: No, I have not  any error mappings (`<error-page``) in my web.xml .

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments most probably there is a new/fresh exception being thrown while instantiating the ErrorPage instance that swallows the original one. Since this happens in `IRequestCycleListener` Wicket does not catch it and letс the servlet container (Tomcat) to handle it.

You can simplify it by adding `<error-page>` mappings in web.xml for each error code you want to handle. Then use `Integer statusCode = (Integer) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");` inside ErrorPage's constructor to get the error code.

See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/servlet-exception-and-error-handling-example-tutorial for a Servlet/non-Wicket example.

Comment: I want to create a unique id for an exception. And if an error is displayed to the user on the screen:
""Error with the id="test", contact the administrator."
And also write the exception id="test" in the log. And then, when the user contacts, get the exception id="test" - and find it in the log.

Comment: Either debug what is the new exception and fix it, or pass the id as attribute as the others.